# Best method for instantiating and registering derived classes with CRTP?

Tags: c++, crtp

I'm a hobbyist programmer trying to learn some of the new C++ idioms (through game development, but that's just the motivation). Previously if I was making something like a simple GUI system which had some derived classes, I would do something like:

```
- class Widget
- class Button : public Widget
- class AdvancedButton : public Button
- etc
```

and I might use a central GUI class to create and manage these widgets:

```
class GUI
{ 
public:
    template <class T> 
    Widget* createWidget() {
        auto new_widget = new T();
        return new_widget;
    }
}
```

This is just a trivial example to illustrate my point. Of course I'd use smart pointers, and I'm typically storing a pointer to the newly created object in a map or list. To instantiate my widgets I'd do:

`auto new_button = gui->createWidget<Button>()` which would automatically create and register the button.

I discovered CRTP when I tried to implement function chaining, and realized it wouldn't work with standard inheritance.

So now instead of standard inheritance, I have:

```
struct BaseWidget {
    virtual ~BaseWidget() {}
};

template <typename Derived>
class Widget : BaseWidget { }
```

and my subclasses are something like:

```
template <typename Derived>
class Label : public Widget<Label<Derived>> {
    virtual Label& setter(int i)   { m_i= i; return static_cast<Derived>(*this); }
}
```

My challenge is that this seems to preclude my original templated way of instantiating the widgets through a central manager class. What is the best alternative when using CRTP?

I hope this makes sense. It's one my first times asking questions here, so if I'm misunderstanding anything fundamental please let me know, definitely very new to this pattern. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide some information on how you'd like to be instantiating your widgets? It's a bit unclear for me what exactly isn't working.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can you elaborate on *"this seems to preclude my original templated way of instantiating the widgets"*?

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying! When I try to call: gui->create_widget<Label>() I get an error of "no matching function call" and "template argument deduction/substitution failed". Do I need to explicitly call create_widget<Label<Widget>>() instead?

Comment: @AndrewLytle May I ask why you are using _static polymorphism_ in this case? Are you working with very limited device resources?

Comment: Like I said, it's purely an academic excercise. That said, I think I've answered my own question. You can't share a pointer to a common base class for all derived classes, because the classes don't share a common base. So I could probably create them in a similar fashion, but I need to store the different object types independently.